# touchstart and swipe not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, swipe

[Pretty simple Bootstrap website](http://gregbensonportfolio.com). I looked up how to enable swiping in a standard lightbox modal and found code that others said worked for them, but it's not working for me.

```
 $('.carousel').bcSwipe({ threshold: 50 });
```

Also, I can't figure out how to add a touchstart to the close button for the modal. I have some experience with JS, but am very new to jQuery. I also know that there are some loading issues with my code that might be the culprit.

Have at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what my browser's development console dumped:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).bcSwipe is not a function TypeError: $(...).bcSwipe is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://gregabyte.nfshost.com/js/script.js:47:18)
at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined
```

I took a look to the source code of your page and i can't see neither `jquery.bcSwipe.js` nor `jquery.bcSwipe.min.js` included in it, so i assume you forgot to include bcSwipe library.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know there was a library for it. I'll include that and see what happens.